# Shopify unparsable structured data. Structured data with syntax errors detected

Tags: shopify, google-search-console, structured-data

I have a similar problem with our Shopify store https://shop.campeasy.com

"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dataset') at u.cartMarkup (https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0583/0973/8659/t/3/assets/theme.min.js?v=1567856883639194316:13:20609)". Any ideas on how can fix structured data in Shopify?

Comment: Where are you seeing this error?  When I visit your site I don't see the error.

Comment: I can see that error in Google Search Console, is not indexing the Urls. I have the same problem with the page https://shop.campeasy.com/collections/mittens but this time the reason can be the script:                                                                          <script type="application/ld+json">    
    "image": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "height": 1000,
      "url": "https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0583\/0973\/8659\/collections\/gilsa-1840110-01_2_1000x.png?v=1630572285",
      "width": 1000
    }

Comment: Where in Google search console do you see this error?  This isn't the type of error I would expect Google Search Console to include in a report.